# First responder/focus after dismissing popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, first-responder

I have a few UITextField inputs on a form screen where some of them have a numpad display that is shown via a custom popover.  As the user advances through the fields, we close or open the popover as appropriate.  In iOS 11, it seems the "first responder" or field focus is returned to the previous input.  As a result, we end up trying to dismiss the main view accidentally.

Is this a known change in iOS 11 or is it a bug?  Is there a way to prevent the first responder from going back, and instead advancing forward or not changing at all - some type of tab index, maybe?

This other SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45953822/710874) presents the same issue, but has not been resolved yet either.  I can't comment on that issue to increase its visibility, hence this new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dismissing the popover in `textFieldShouldEndEditing` (and returning true) instead of `textFieldDidEndEditing` worked for me.